# Wordpress - Loop with images from post to

Tags: wordpress

I made an Wordpress theme, with pages and posts.
The loop of posts show me a short brief of post and a **Continue reading** link.
I like this, but how can I make the theme show in the post brief of the loop image(s) attached to post at beginning, if any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your attached images by using:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts($args);
```

and display it like this:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image($images[0]->ID, $size='attached-image');
```

Answer (score 2):

This for getting all attachement images with your post.

```
   $args = array( 
                 'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                 'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                 'post_status' => null, 
                 'post_parent' => $post->ID 
           );

   $attachments = get_posts( $args );

   if ($attachments) {
      foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
         $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID, 'medium'); 
         $fullsize = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID, 'full');
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your loop:

```
<?php
   if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
      $theimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
}
?>
<img class="img_class" src="<?php echo $theimage[0]; ?>" />
```

Where `"thumbnail"` correspond to the size you want to show.

Remember that there is also a [WordPress specific site in StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I know this method, but this only shows the featured image, not images inserted in post text.

Comment: So, you ask for something like this? [Get first image from post](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it)

Comment: if you're not using wordpress's image manager to add images to post, you will have to use that solution. But, if you indeed using wordpress's image manager, you might want to use answeres my solution. Because, doing regex on post is not really clever solution. Supposed you have smiley on your post and it's first to appear, you'll end up displaying that.